# Spring MVC URL redirect before controller request mappings are called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.2.8. I get a mapping from a URL p to a URL q from an external API. The mapping changes at runtime. I want to redirect (302) the URL before the controller request mappings are called. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try with Interceptors or write a generic filter which will redirect based on some param in the request.

Comment: The problem is: there are no params in the URL. Here an example: the URL ```/foo``` should redirect to ```/?id=123```. The second URL is processing by a controller request mapping method. I have to map these URLs first, because there are no distinguishing features in the URLs I want to map. I will try with an Interceptor.

Comment: You could write an Interceptor that allow a configurable map of urls to there proper final mapping.  Then you could change and edit the mapping however you see fit.

Comment: And how can I handle redirect loops?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. A default controller mapping for every `RequestMethod.GET` request is called if the requested URL does not exist. You have also to load static content (images, css, js, …) by your servlet container without touching Spring.

```
@Controller
public class DynamicURIForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forward(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        // Stuff comes here.
        // final String forwardURI = ...
        return "forward:" + forwardURI;
    }
}
```